# this.props.dispatch is not a function. Not able to dispatch mapdispatchtoprops

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've been trying to dispatch a function that will call an async parse cloud function. It worked well in my other projects when i used them in functions. But this is the first time i'm using them in a component and when i call the dispatch from map dispatch to props, I get this error. Please help me out.

**ProfileHeader.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Cover_Image from './Cover_Image.jpg';
import Profile_Pic from './Profile_Pic.svg';
import './ProfileHeader.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchUserProfile } from '../../Redux/UserProfile-Redux/UserProfileActionMethods';

class ProfileHeader extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchUserProfile()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="profile-header-layout"></div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStatetoProps = (state) => {
  return {
    profile: state.UserProfile
  }
}

const mapDispatchtoProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchUserProfile: () => { dispatch(fetchUserProfile()) }, dispatch,
  }
}

export default connect(mapDispatchtoProps, mapStatetoProps)(ProfileHeader)
```

The action Method:

```js
import Parse from 'parse/dist/parse.min.js';
import { FETCH_USERPROFILE_FAILURE, FETCH_USERPROFILE_REQUEST, FETCH_USERPROFILE_SUCCESS } from './UserProfileActions';

const params = { username: "prvnngrj" }

export const fetchUserProfileRequest = () => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_USERPROFILE_REQUEST
  }
}

export const fetchUserProfileSuccess = (userprofiles) => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_USERPROFILE_SUCCESS,
    payload: userprofiles
  }
}

export const fetchUserProfileFailure = (error) => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_USERPROFILE_FAILURE,
    payload: error
  }
}

export const fetchUserProfile = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchUserProfileRequest)
    try {
      const responsedata = await Parse.Cloud.run("GetUserProfileForUsername", params);
      const userprofiles = responsedata;
      dispatch(fetchUserProfileSuccess(userprofiles))

    }
    catch (error) {
      const errorMessage = error.message
      dispatch(fetchUserProfileFailure(errorMessage))
    }
  }

}
```

Please ignore parts of code which do not make it relevant, its straight from the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed up the order of your arguments, so `this.props.dispatch` is actually your state!

You need to change

```
export default connect(mapDispatchtoProps, mapStatetoProps)(ProfileHeader)
```

to:

```
export default connect(mapStatetoProps, mapDispatchtoProps)(ProfileHeader)
```

If you can switch to function components and the `useSelector`/`useDispatch` hooks you should.  This is the current recommended approach and it's easier to use.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much, I also have another question, how do i bring in the profile as a prop and display its data ? when i use a map function, it tells me that map isnt a function.

Comment: Please help me sir, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67180197/how-to-pass-props-data-from-render-to-handlesubmit-function-in-redux